# Cannot create a formatted pandas multindex barplot?

Tags: python, pandas, bar-chart, multi-index

I have a multiindex pandas dataframe that looks like this:

```
            cis-aconitate  cis-aconitate +1  ...  cis-aconitate +5  cis-aconitate +6
     GROUP                                   ...                                    
mean ADE         1.481639          0.696184  ...          0.193380          0.018597
     VEH         1.000000          1.000000  ...          1.000000          1.000000
std  ADE         0.307211          0.209418  ...          0.114939          0.020461
     VEH         0.573162          0.412895  ...          0.384928          0.752999
```

With indexing like this:

```
MultiIndex([('mean', 'ADE'),
            ('mean', 'VEH'),
            ( 'std', 'ADE'),
            ( 'std', 'VEH')],
           names=[None, 'GROUP'])
```

I am trying to create a barplot of the mean values on the y-axis. Using `df.unstack()` and then `df.plot.bar()` I can get this: [image]
But what I would ultimately like is to have the means only, with 'cis-aconitate, cis-aconitate +1 ...' across the x-axis, grouped into ADE and VEH (one color each) and then 'std' values used for the error bars. This is proving surprisingly tricky. Can anyone help? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To avoid doing a lot of transformations to the data frame and based on [this example](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/visualization.html#visualization-errorbars), the solution I found was to split the means from the errors using [cross section](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.xs.html?highlight=xs#pandas.DataFrame.xs).

```py
import pandas as pd

# Example data
index = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples([('mean', 'ADE'), ('mean', 'VEH'), ( 'std', 'ADE'), ('std', 'VEH')], names=[None, 'GROUP'])

df = pd.DataFrame({'cis-aconitate': [1.5, 1, 0.3, 0.2], 'cis-aconitate +1': [0.7, 1, 0.2, 0.4]}, index=index)
df

# Split dataframe into means and errors
means = df.xs('mean').transpose()
errors = df.xs('std').transpose()

means.plot.bar(yerr=errors)
```

Comment: If you have access to the data that originated this data frame, [seaborn](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.barplot.html?highlight=barplot#seaborn.barplot) can also be a nice alternative, as you'll probably only need to melt the data and have a 'group' column. It plots error bars as confidence intervals by default, but you can specify standard deviation.

Comment: This worked brilliantly! Thank you! Cross section with transpose was the key. I will definitely explore using seaborn with the long form data too. Will likely lead to more elegant code. Thanks very much for you help!